# C# Selenium - Firing an onChange Dispatch Event

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Previously I had made an Excel Macro that took data from an Excel sheet and entered it into the appropriate fields on a webpage.  Sometimes the Excel data was incomplete so there would be empty cells.  Because the form I was filling out had validation I wasn't able to click the submit button and the script would break.  To work around this I would manually fire the onChange dispatch event even if the cell was blank.  This is an example of a Drop down menu.

```
Set doc = IE.document
Set event_onChange = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False

stateName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_1").Cells(2, 10).Value

doc.querySelector("[id^='new'][id$='-SourceState']").Value = stateName
doc.querySelector("[id^='new'][id$='-SourceState']").dispatchEvent event_onChange

doc.querySelector("#nav-Form > button[class^='btn submit']").Click
```

This worked fine, even if the cell was blank the Submit button would enable and allow me to save.  After all the information was entered a user would go back through and look for the missing data and manually input it.  Any missing data was highlighted red and easy to find.

I am trying to re-create my script in C# and Selenium and have pretty much everything working except this onChange event.  I switched from using IE to Chrome.  Right now I have this.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

string strStateName = Convert.ToString(xlRange.Cells[2, 10].Value2);
var eState = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[id^='new'][id$='-SourceState']")));
var selectState = new SelectElement(eState);
if (strStateName != null)
{
    selectState.SelectByText(strStateName);
}

var eSave = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#nav-Form > button[class^='btn submit']")));
eSave.Click();
```

If the Excel field is filled out it works fine, but if it's blank then the "Save" button doesn't work because it's unclickable due to the validation on the webpage.

I tried a few different things but I wasn't able to get either of them to work.

```
if (strStateName != null)
{
    selectState.SelectByText(strStateName);
}
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))", driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id^='new'][id$='-SourceState']")));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));", driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id^='new'][id$='-SourceState']")));
```

Is there any other way I can trigger this onChange dispatch event?  I know that having incomplete data isn't the best case scenario but I'd rather enter as much as possible first and then go back and look for the missing data rather than the program stopping because of missing data.

Comment: Could you just set strStateName to "NA"?  I don't think you can pass a webelement into that script.  Use standard javascript to select the input field.

Comment: The eState webelement is a dropdown list.  There is no "NA" option in the dropdown list so it will throw an error.  I'm not sure what you mean by using standard javascript to select the input field.

Comment: something like document.getElementByID('id');...